# WebView does not show all of the webpage's contents

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, html

I would like to show this webpage using an Android WebView, but the WebView does not show the full contents of the webpage.

I enabled javascript but some items still do not appear:

```
public class MyCustomListView extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    private Button refresh;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_custom_list_view);




        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.60/george-steuart/van/drawWeb?wuid=40da9b9ed74f672c3871d76a2c87857b");



        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;

            }
        });

        refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);

        refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View mView) {
                webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.1.60/george-steuart/van/drawWeb?wuid=40da9b9ed74f672c3871d76a2c87857b");

            }
        });


    }

    }
```

Comment: Are you testing this on phone or emulator ??

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "some item do not appear" ? Can you please elaborate a bit or paste some screenshot..

Comment: This might be the reason your web designer made a jQuery/JS that your device browser is not understanding so it stop to parse complete HTML Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getField() {
    id++;
    document.getElementById("hide").value = id;
    $('#tbl1').append(
            '<tr id="select_row_' + id + '">'
            + '<td><img algn="center" src="' + URL + '../../../public/images/add.png" width="30" height="30" alt="add" id="addrow_' + id + '" onclick="getField();" /></td>'
            + '<td><input type="text" style="border-radius: 5px;height: 35px;width: 200px" id="item_name_' + id + '" placeholder="Select Item" autocomplete="off" onfocus="getMaterial(' + id + ')" ></td>'
            + '<td><input type="text" style="border-radius: 5px;height: 35px;width: 100px" name="qty_' + id + '" id="qty_' + id + '" placeholder="Input Quantity"></td>'
            + '<td><img src="' + URL + '../../../public/images/remove.png" id="addrow_' + id + '" onclick="remove_data_row(' + id + ');" width="20" height="20" alt="add"/></td>'
            + '<input type="hidden" id="iid_' + id + '" name="iid_' + id + '"/>'
            + '</tr>'
            );
}
```

this is the java script code.the problem with this URL variable it works on web browser.but not in webview.He(Web developer) changed it and give absolute path.Now it works.

Comment: Try this, some java script does not work in web view.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code it works

```
private ProgressDialog progDailog;
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(MyCustomListView.this, "Loading",
                "Please wait...", true);
progDailog.setCancelable(false);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            webView .getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView .getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webView .getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);        
            webView .loadUrl("http://192.168.1.60/george-steuart/van/drawWeb?wuid=40da9b9ed74f672c3871d76a2c87857b");
            // following lines are to show the loader untile downloading
            // file for view.
            webView .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    progDailog.show();
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }          

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                    progDailog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I got the answer...
the problem is one java script variable does not work in web view our web developer solve it...

Comment: I post my answer.we fixed it thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

use server instead of checking it on LAN

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you give permission for internet in Manifest file

Comment: -1 because OP half page content is showing as per the question. So it is of course, OP added that permission